# integrate google drive into zegoclound - project in nextjs

Tags: next.js, google-drive-api, zegocloud

I'm using zegocloud in my nextjs app
I would like to understand if it is possible to integrate Google Drive so that, for example, if I want to share an image I can get it from the drive and not from the PC itself.